# What is considered to be my submission if I change the format of an input from 'radio' to 'checkbox' using 'inspect element' in my browser

Tags: html, server, backend

If this is how it was initially.

```
    <input name="quiz" id="4" value="4" type="radio">
    <input name="quiz" id="2" value="2" type="radio">
    <input name="quiz" id="3" value="1" type="radio">
    <input name="quiz" id="1" value="3" type="radio">
```

What if i change it like..

```
<input name="quiz" id="4" value="4" type="checkbox">
<input name="quiz" id="2" value="2" type="checkbox">
<input name="quiz" id="3" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input name="quiz" id="1" value="3" type="checkbox">
```

..and click all of the above options and submit my form.
Will it consider the all the options or the one checked the last?

Comment: it really depends on the server behavior. I'd say that nothing would happen and the form would not be sumbited to a DB because the type is not the one expected. Also there will likely be a javascript check of the form before sending it.

Comment: All of them. For example if all checkboxes are checked then you get `quiz=4&quiz=2&quiz=1&quiz=3`

Comment: @VictorSmt I tried doing this in my college's Feedback form and submitted the Form.
Surprisingly it got submitted.

Comment: haha ok then they have a poor backend I guess and @SalmanA is probably right

Comment: @SalmanA In that case,what would the program consider,as i believe that it wouldn't have expected such an input  as said by VictorSmt ?
Since it doesn't have such kind of an expectation would the question not be evaluated or would the program which is written for the total score stop?

Comment: @Satya I did not say how the server handles them. If it is a PHP script it will have `$_POST = array("quiz" => "3")`. If it was ASP then `Request.Form("quiz")` will be a collection containing 4 items and if you use it in string context then it will be string `"4, 2, 1, 3"`. The scripting engine decides how to handle post data such as `a=1&a=2`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a hypothetical question with no knowable answer.